# Secret sharing for a general access structure

Tags: cryptography

A secret sharing scheme is a method of distributing finite pieces of information (called shares $\alpha_i$) among a set of players $P=\{1,\ldots, k\}$ in such a way that only certain subsets of players $S \subseteq P$ (the authorized coalitions) can use their shares to compute certain piece of information $\sigma$ (called the secret).
The subset $\mathcal{A} \subseteq 2^P$ consisting of all the authorized
coalitions is called the access structure of the scheme.

An scheme is called  $(t,k)$-threshold if its access structure consists of all the subsets of $P$ with $t$ or more elements. A well-known $(k,k)$-threshold scheme
(where the only authorized coalition is the full set of players $P$)
is described below.

#### $\oplus$-additive $(k,k)$-threshold scheme:

Let us fix the size ($N$ bits) of the space where the secret and the shares are located. Then:

1. encode the secret as a binary string $\sigma \in \{0,1\}^N$;
2. for $i= 1,\ldots, k-1$, (privately) give to the $i$-th player a
   random binary string $\alpha_i \in \{0,1\}^N$;
3. (privately) give to the $k$-th player the string
       $\alpha_k = \sigma \oplus \alpha_1 \oplus \alpha_2 \oplus \cdots \oplus \alpha_{k-1}$, where $\oplus$ denotes the standard component-wise addition modulo $2$ (aka.~$\mathsf{XOR}$).
4. Now, in order to recover the secret (for the authorized coalition
   $P$), it is enough to $\oplus$-add the full set of shares; whereas
   any non-full coalition will only obtain a random string (in
   $\{0,1\}^N$) after $\oplus$-adding the respective shares.

My question relates to the following naive attempt of generalization of the previous idea to a general access structure.

#### (Tentative) $\oplus$-additive general scheme:

Let
$P = \{1, \ldots,k\}$, and
let
$\mathcal{A} \subseteq 2^{P}$ be an arbitrary access structure on $P$. Then,

1. encode the secret as a binary string $\sigma \in \{0,1\}^N$;
2. for $i= 1,\ldots, k$, (privately) give to the $i$-th player a random
   binary string $\alpha_i \in \{0,1\}^N$;
3. for every subset $S_j \subseteq 2^P$, let
       $\beta_j = \big(\bigoplus\nolimits_{\alpha_i \in S_j} \alpha_i\big) \oplus \sigma_j$ ,
       where $\sigma_j$ is a random binary string in $\{0,1\}^N \setminus \{\sigma\}$ if $S_j \notin \mathcal{A}$, and $\sigma_j =
   \sigma$ if $S_j \in \mathcal{A}$; and make the correspondence $j
   \mapsto \beta_j$ publicly available.
4. Now, for any coalition $S_j \in \mathcal{A}$, the computation:
       $\big(\bigoplus\nolimits_{\alpha_i \in S_j} \alpha_i\big) \oplus \beta_j$
       provides the secret if $S_j \in \mathcal{A}$, and a random string (different from the secret) otherwise.

My questions are:

1. does this second scheme have any irreparable flaws?
2. in the negative case, I suppose that this scheme is already known.
   Does it have a name? Do you know any reference to it?
3. in the (very improbable) case that the scheme is reasonable and not already
   studied, I would be grateful if someone can provide some feedback
   about its potential, weaknesses, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this $\beta_j = \big(\bigoplus\nolimits_{\alpha_i \in S_j} \alpha_i\big) \oplus \sigma_j$ tranleated to $\beta_j=\sum_{\alpha_i \in S_j} \alpha_i\oplus \sigma_j$? If yes, why do we write $\bigoplus\nolimits_{\alpha_i \in S_j}\alpha_i$ instead of $\sum_{\alpha_i \in S_j} \alpha_i$?

Answer (score 2):

Your step 3 seems designed to hide $\mathcal A$, which isn't a standard requirement of secret-sharing schemes. If you simplify it to produce an encoded string for each authorized coalition instead of for every subset of $P$, then you have what Wikipedia describes as the "trivial" scheme: the $(k,k)$-threshold scheme applied separately to each authorized coalition. The main thing making this impractical (as a $(t,k)$-threshold scheme) is that the space requirement is proportional to the number of authorized coalitions.

Comment: Thanks @Karl.  I am not sure about what you mean by "coalition" (to me "coalition" is just the same as "subset of players"). On the other side, although I agree that there are similitudes between my tentative scheme and the one you mention (using multiple trivial schemes) it seems that there are also (important?) differences. In particular, the number of shares is linear (instead of exponential) in the number of players, right?

Comment: Also, my point in step 3 was not hiding the $\mathcal{A}$ but just making sure that a coalition computes the secret if and only if it belongs to $\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: Oh sorry, by "coalition" I meant an authorized coalition, i.e. an element of $\mathcal A$. Your scheme creates $2^{|P|}$ strings $\beta_j$ if I inderstand it correctly.